# JSON Parsing Failed?

Tags: objective-c

I am writing the code using "NSstring + SBJSON" as follows.

```
_responseData = [NSMutableData data];

NSString *stringOfRequest=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@LinkAsset?linked1=%@&linked2=%@&userid=%@",Service_URL,linkAsset,linkAsset2,app._userid];
NSMutableString * _req = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stringOfRequest];
[_req  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
_requestForUrl = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                  [NSURL URLWithString:
                   [_req  stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];
_nsurlConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:_requestForUrl delegate:self];
```

Im getting the error.

```
 -JSONValue failed. Error trace is: (
"Error Domain=org.brautaset.JSON.ErrorDomain Code=4 \"Valid fragment, but not JSON\" UserInfo=0x797f17d0 {NSLocalizedDescription=Valid fragment, but not JSON}")
```

In my code if I am giving another json string than it is working. And also my original json string is giving me the data in browser. So what to do?

My getting the Response code,

```
 NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     responseData= nil;
   productArray = [responseString JSONValue];
    NSLog(@"Product Array %@", productArray);
```

Every time Im getting the Same Issue.

Comment: So what's this 'bad' json string look like?

Comment: Have you put your JSON through a JSON validator?